# Storing custom configuration in android

Tags: java, android, xml, configuration

I am creating an android application and i need to manage how to display data of list view in some fragment .. My list view consists of multiple sections with a header on each section.. The data of these sections are loaded from a web service(web call for each section) and i need to manage which sections to display to the user and also sort the sections by priority so that the important sections are displayed at the top of the view.

My question is how can i make this configurable and loaded once in my application so that when getting the data i can construct the list view properly using an already loaded configuration, i thought of using **SharedPreferences** or maybe an **XML file** as a configuration storage.

Again, my interests are to:

- Manage which sections to be viewed in my list view. (for all users and not per user)
- Sort the sections by priorities.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have a database and store the settings for each user there. Based on data stored in the database you can generate XML, if needed. This would be very useful, as if you open the application with another android phone, but log in with your user, your settings would be loaded as well.

Comment: The settings are not per user .. these settings should be set once at the application startup and when accessing the fragment it should have access to these settings as an object and load the sections and sort them based on the value of the object's properties something like that.

Comment: Then you can include the settings into an xml and when you initialize your project upon startup, then you can set the values into an object reachable from everywhere.

Comment: Sorry , your answer doesn't help me